# how to use a parameter in a function that calls a reduced function

Tags: javascript

I am kind of lost on how to use the letter parameter inside the reduce function. Just doing cur.letter doesnt allow me to use it. Not sure what is causing the issue. I was able to use "letter" outside the reduce function.

The array I am using is really large in data, so I made a mock array which is similar to the array I am using.

```js
calculateForAllLetter(arr, letter) {
  return arr.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
    return prev + parseInt(cur.letter);
  }, 0);
}
const arr = [{
  A: 10,
  B: 10,
  C: 10
}, {
  A: 10,
  B: 10,
  C: 10
}, {
  A: 10,
  B: 10,
  C: 10
}, {
  A: 10,
  B: 10,
  C: 10
}]

const totalGradesA = this.calculateForAllLetter(arr, "A")

console.log(totalGradesA)
```

Comment: Please post the array you are reducing and letter in a [mcve]

Comment: Perhaps you need `return prev + parseInt(cur[letter]);`?  But more information would make that clear.

Comment: I made a snippet. Please fix it to be a [mcve]

Comment: This has nothing to do with `reduce`, you'd have the same problem accessing a dynamic property without reduce, wouldn't you?

Comment: You can also dynamically access that variable inside some parameter destructuring, to lead to this version: `const calculateForAllLetter = (arr, letter) => arr .reduce ((total, {[letter]: ltr}) => total + ltr, 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the docs for the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method. You need to have a function that takes the accumulated value so far, and the current item, and then return the combination of these. As the `currentItem` each iteration is an object, you can use `[letter]` to get the contents you need.

```js
function calculateForAllLetter(arr, letter) {
  return arr.reduce(function(accumulated, currentItem) {
    return accumulated + currentItem[letter];
  }, 0);
}

const arr = [{A: 10, B: 10, C: 10}, {A: 10, B: 10, C: 10}, {A: 10, B: 10, C: 10}, {A: 10, B: 10, C: 10}]

const totalGradesA = this.calculateForAllLetter(arr, "A")

console.log(totalGradesA)
```

Comment: This answered my question. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

```
calculateForAllLetter(arr, letter){
    return arr.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
      return prev + cur[letter];
    }, 0);
  }
```